# VLookup with Multiple Criteria with VBA and the array formula method

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

So the idea is to make use of the beautiful Array Formula Method and the idea behind it, when it is needed to make a VLookUp with multiple criteria in VBA.

**The question:**
can we translate this into VBA:

`{=INDEX(range1,MATCH(1,(A1=range2)*(B1=range3)*(C1=range4),0))}`

Without using formulas in Excel at all? E.g., without doing this:

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, '[TUR Master Report.xlsm]Archive'!$B$2:$B$13/
                  (('[TUR Master Report.xlsm]Archive'!$B$2:$B$13>=DO2)*
                   ('[TUR Master Report.xlsm]Archive'!$B$2:$B$13<=DP2)*
                   ('[TUR Master Report.xlsm]Archive'!$A$2:$A$13=A2)), 1)
```

or anything similar (`.ArrayFormula`,`.Formula`, etc).

I was thinking about something like this
`foo = Match(1,(A1=rangeA)*(B1=rangeB)*(C1=rangeC),0)`, but of course it does not work, although it is in the logic of the Excel formula. So far I have created the following as a workaround:

```
Function GetLookupDataTriple(tableName As String, lookIntoColumn As String, myArray As Variant) As Variant
    
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects(tableName)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lo.ListColumns(myArray(0)).Range.Rows.Count
        If lo.ListColumns(myArray(0)).Range.Cells(RowIndex:=i) = myArray(1) Then
            If lo.ListColumns(myArray(2)).Range.Cells(RowIndex:=i) = myArray(3) Then
                If lo.ListColumns(myArray(4)).Range.Cells(RowIndex:=i) = myArray(5) Then
                    GetLookupDataTriple = lo.ListColumns(lookIntoColumn).Range.Cells(RowIndex:=i)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    GetLookupDataTriple = -1
    
End Function
```

which works quite ok with 3 filters, but the idea is to be a bit fancier, e.g. like in the excel original formula. This is a sample data, that makes the function above work:

[image]

`?GetLookupDataTriple("Table1","To",array("From","Bulgaria","Cost",200,"Currency","USD"))`

Comment: I guess it would depend on what you mean by "fancier".  What you've listed is my typical function style (though I tend to use `And` for two criteria, but stick to multiple `If` statements when I have 3+).  You could have a sub loop that verifies each criteria is met in its own array, if you want to avoid the embedded if statements, but this would probably just lengthen your already succinct code.

Comment: As a fancy I am looking for something like this `foo = Match(1,(A1=rangeA)*(B1=rangeB)*(C1=rangeC),0)`, small and understanding. There should be a built-in way to do it in VBA, I am guessing.

Comment: No built-in way to do this in VBA AFAIK. Probably using 3 Variant arrays of similar size and looping is one option.

Comment: The only way I know of would be to use worksheet().Evaluate().  vba cannot multiply arrays and return an array, without programing a function yourself to do so, which is necessary for this to work.

Comment: Is your worry the fact that you want something that will take two, three, four, or more Booleans and return the match?  If so a properly written function that uses paramArray should be elastic enough to do so.

Comment: @ScottCraner - somehow my worry my that a rather simple Excel array formula can do something that VBA would need multiple non standard lines of code.

Comment: @Vityata Posted an approach creating quasi-boolean array blocks via `Application.Index` and profiting from the use of a `ParamArray`.

Comment: Any interest in a dynamic SQL answer? I think that could work fairly well in addressing having variable number of arguments.

Comment: @RyanWildry - give it a try, but I think it will be an overkill.

Comment: @Vityata It seems to be a strange game that all of the up-voted answers here were, as it were, brought back to a uniform zero with a down-vote. - Allow me as suggestion: Perhaps you could not only specify the goal of the question, but also the functionality of your workaround based on a reproducable set of example data, in order to achieve a (even) broader understanding of the question at least for (future) readers.

Comment: @T.M. - you have a point, added a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

**A) VBA *"VLookup"* based on *ListObject* data**

As you refer to a *ListObject* in OP, I focussed upon an approach based *entirely* on *listobject data*.

As a practical surplus it would be *neat* to identify column references by existing *table headers* or *index numbers*. So the function **`multCrit()`** below returns the value of a given column (`retCol`) with any number of column criteria.

> *"As a fancy I am looking for something like this `foo = Match(1,(A1=rangeA)*(B1=rangeB)*(C1=rangeC),0)`,
> small and understanding."*

Organizing inputs in a `ParamArray` might help at least to hold the function call *small* and *clear*, e.g. via the following pseudo syntax

```
multCrit(lo, ReturnColumn, ParamArray:{Col1, search1, Col2, search2,...})
```

*Note that I only reversed the input order within the ParamArray.*

**Needed Arguments**

- 1st argument `data` identifies a *ListObject*,
- 2nd argument `retCol` identifies the column to be returned (header or index),
- 3rd 0-based argument `ParamArray arr()` allows multiple inputs in the following order:

```
       - even inputs identify column (by header string or index number)
       - odd  inputs define a search value (e.g. explicitly or as cell reference)
```

> *"There should be a built-in way to do it in VBA, I am guessing."*

Methodically this approach tries to

- get **column array blocks** for each criteria (in one go via `Application.Index()` *- note the use of* **two** *array arguments!*)
- within a temporary array container `tmp` (aka as jagged array) and
- showing value `1` for findings (and #NV error 2042 for non-findings) in each criteria block.

This allows to identify value `1` *sequences* in all indicated column **blocks**, even if this approach **doesn't** dispose of a **built-in** check by multiplying boolean values as in Excel functions. - *Of course there are still several opportunities for improvement (e.g. to find the next possible item instead of row-wise loops), but it shows the way.*

**Function `multCrit()`**

```
Function multCrit(data As ListObject, ByVal retCol, ParamArray crit() As Variant) As Variant

'0) provide for 0-based temporary array container (aka jagged critay)
    Dim critCnt As Long: critCnt = (UBound(crit) + 1) \ 2
    Dim tmp: ReDim tmp(0 To critCnt - 1)
    
'1) include an array/column in one go into temporary array container
    Dim c As Long
    For c = LBound(crit) To UBound(crit) Step 2
        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        'execute 1 Match/col ~~> found elements receive value 1 (non-findings error 2042)
        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        tmp(c \ 2) = Application.Match(getCol(data, crit(c)), Array(crit(c + 1)), 0)
        'Debug.Print "tmp(" & c \ 2 & ")", "header: " & crit(c), data.ListColumns(crit(c)).Index, crit(c + 1)
    Next
    
'2) get lookup value as soon as all column values in a given row equal 1
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(tmp(0))
        For c = 0 To UBound(tmp)
            'check next row, if no value 1 found
            If IsError(tmp(c)(r, 1)) Then Exit For  ' escape to check next row
            If c = UBound(tmp) Then                 ' struggled through to last element
                'get result value of found row from referenced retCol
                multCrit = getCol(data, retCol)(r, 1): Exit Function
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End Function
```

**Help function `getCol()`**

Returns column data identified by **header** *name* or *index number* of the ListObject:

```
Function getCol(data As ListObject, header)
'Purp:  get listobject column data via header (either string or index number)
    getCol = data.DataBodyRange.Columns(data.ListColumns(header).Index)
End Function
```

**Example Call**

Note that the function allows *any order* of header (and search item) inputs, whether explicitly or as range reference; so this example demonstrates a *modified column order* and range inputs, too:

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    'example display in VB Editor's immediate window: ~~> EN
    Debug.Print "*~~>", multCrit(lo, "lang", "Col2", "two", "Col3", "three", "Col1", Sheet1.Range("B1"))
End Sub
```

[image: listobject example]

**Possible code extension** // *edited 2021-12-12*

If you don't insist to return a *value* *(being typical for a `VLookUp` solution)*, but to return the found *data* **row** as further option, you might

- provide e.g. for passing a zero-input (`0`) to argument `retCol` and
- change the last code part of function `MultCrit()` as follows:

```
                'get result value of found row from referenced retCol
                If retCol = 0 Then                  ' special arg 0: return row
                    multCrit = r
                Else                                ' default: return value
                    multCrit = getCol(data, retCol)(r, 1): Exit Function
                End If
```

Then displaying via `Debug.Print "*~~>", multCrit(lo, 0, "Col2", "two", "Col3", "three", "Col1", Sheet1.Range("B1"))` would show e.g. the 2nd row as numeric result: `~~> 2`.

---

**B) Short alternative via XlRangeValueDataType enumeration in `.Value(12)`** *// ►late Edit as of 2021-12-13◄*

> This methodically **new approach** is based entirely on a string analysis of `.Value(`[xlRangeValueMSPersistXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlrangevaluedatatype)`)` - also known as `.Value(12)` -, which returns the recordset representation of the specified (ListObject) range as **XML formatted** string.

- A **snippet example** of a row node holding column info attributes `Col1`, `Col2` etc could be:

```
<xml><!-- omitting all namespace definitions -->
  <!-- omitted ... -->
  <rs:data>
   <z:row Col1="DE" Col2="eins" Col3="zwei" Col4="drei"/>
   <!-- etc... -->
  </rs:data>
 </x:PivotCache>
</xml>
```

Applying ► **`FilterXML`** on this *(slightly transformed)* *content* via an **XPath** search expression combining all criteria conditions programatically, like here e.g.

```
    "//zrow[@Col3='two' and @Col4='three' and @Col2='one']/@Col1"`
```

allows to return the indexed column value passed by argument `retCol`. *(Note that I transform the original content to allow an easier search without namespace issues, c.f. `zrow` instead of `z:row`)

This example can be called similar to ExampleCall in case A (*but* wouldn't return a row index as proposed in *"Possible code extensions"*).

```
Function MultCrit12(lo As ListObject, ByVal retCol, ParamArray crit() As Variant) As Variant
'1) get FilterXML arguments
'   a) Arg1: wellformed xml content string (xlRangeValueMSPersistXML = 12)
    Dim content As String
    content = Replace(lo.Range.Value(12), ":", "")
    
'   b) Arg2: XPath by analyzing ParamArray crit()
    Dim c As Long
    Dim XPath As String: XPath = "//zrow["
    For c = LBound(crit) To UBound(crit) Step 2
        XPath = XPath & " and @Col" & lo.ListColumns(crit(c)).Index & "='" & crit(c + 1) & "'"
    Next
    If VarType(retCol) = vbString Then retCol = lo.ListColumns(retCol).Index   ' get column index of header
    XPath = Replace(XPath, "[ and ", "[") & "]/@Col" & retCol

'2) apply FilterXML upon above arguments
    With Application
        Dim ret
        ret = .FilterXML(content, XPath)   ' << FilterXML
        If VarType(ret) > vbArray Then
            MultCrit12 = ret(1, 1)
        Else
            MultCrit12 = ret
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Definitely an interesting one, but looks tough to grasp immediately if I implement it in my code.

Comment: Thx for feedback. - Fyi Added a possible extension to return a found row value as further option @Vityata

Comment: Posted a completely new approach using FilterXML based on  XlRangeValueDataType enumeration in section B) @Vityata

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a way to lookup n number of criteria?

assuming the following data:

[image]

You could use XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP(1&1&1,A1:A9&B1:B9&C1:C9,D1:D9,"Not Found";)
```

This will find the last row where a,b, and c = 1 and result is 8

Comment: Albeit a handy use in Excel, the question specifically refers to the multiple criteria in VBA without using `Application` functions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, but this is the thing I want to "translate" into VBA. But without using `.Formula` or anything similar. E.g., if it is possible to translate the ranges to VBA ranges/arrays and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Moving to `Select Case` from Ifs would at least make things cleaner to add more criteria later (cleanliness is fanciness?); just add new cases, rather than messing with `If` and spacing, etc.  My mock-up:

```
For i = 2 To lo.ListColumns(myArray(0)).Range.Rows.Count
    Select Case False
        Case lo.ListColumns(myArray(0)).Range.Cells(RowIndex:=i) = myArray(1)
        Case lo.ListColumns(myArray(2)).Range.Cells(RowIndex:=i) = myArray(3)
        Case lo.ListColumns(myArray(4)).Range.Cells(RowIndex:=i) = myArray(5)
        Case Else 
            GetLookupDataTriple = lo.ListColumns(lookIntoColumn).Range.Cells(RowIndex:=i)
            Exit For
    End Select
Next i
```

This definitely isn't down to your `foo = Match(1,(A1=rangeA)*(B1=rangeB)*(C1=rangeC),0)` level of fancy/clean, though.

Comment: This one is beautiful & works, thanks. Still, looking for the `=Match(1,(condition)*(condition)` that are translated to Boolean values though...

Comment: Yeah, I'm waiting to see how this whole thing pans out (bookmarked)... a nice mental stumper for the day, as I default to what you have or the above, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How abut the following:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Dim myArray(5) As Variant
myArray(0) = "a"
myArray(1) = 1
myArray(2) = "b"
myArray(3) = 1
myArray(4) = "c"
myArray(5) = 1

    MsgBox (GetLookupDataTriple2("Table1", "result", myArray))
End Sub


Function GetLookupDataTriple2(tableName As String, lookIntoColumn As String, myArray As Variant) As Variant
    
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects(tableName)
    
    noOfSearchParam = UBound(myArray) - LBound(myArray)
    
    Dim found As Boolean
    
    For i = 2 To lo.ListColumns(myArray(0)).Range.Rows.Count
     found = True
        For s = 0 To noOfSearchParam Step 2
            If lo.ListColumns(myArray(s)).Range.Cells(RowIndex:=i) <> myArray(s + 1) Then
                 found = False
            End If
        Next s
        If found Then
            GetLookupDataTriple2 = lo.ListColumns(lookIntoColumn).Range.Cells(RowIndex:=i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    GetLookupDataTriple2 = -1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

the worksheet will allow the multiplication/addition of arrays, but vba does not. That is the root of the issue. As to why....I do not know but I assume since we can loop in vba but not in formulas(at least till they invented the dynamic array formula) they created the ability in the worksheet but not vba.

Therefore there is no way to simply use MATCH.  We need to program our own function to simplify the entry.

---

Here is a paramarray version of match that accepts any number of vertical arrays of the same size or ranges of the same size and returns the relative row number:

```
Function myArrayMatch(ParamArray arr() As Variant) As Long
    If UBound(arr) Mod 2 <> 1 Then
        myArrayMatch = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim lgth As Long
    If TypeName(arr(LBound(arr))) = "Range" Then
        lgth = Intersect(arr(LBound(arr)).Parent.UsedRange, arr(LBound(arr))).Cells.Count
    Else
        lgth = UBound(arr(LBound(arr))) + LBound(arr(LBound(arr))) - 1
    End If
    Dim fnd() As Boolean
    ReDim fnd(1 To lgth) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 2
        Dim rngarr As Variant
        If TypeName(arr(i)) = "Range" Then
            rngarr = Intersect(arr(i).Parent.UsedRange, arr(i))
        Else
            rngarr = arr(i)
        End If
        Dim j As Long
            For j = 1 To lgth
            If rngarr(j - IIf(LBound(rngarr, 1) = 0, 1, 0), 1) = arr(i + 1) Then
                If i = LBound(arr) Then fnd(j) = True
            Else
                fnd(j) = False
            End If
            If i = UBound(arr) - 1 And fnd(j) Then
                myArrayMatch = j
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
                
End Function
```

It can be called like:

```
relRow = myArrayMatch(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"),"X",ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"),"Y")
```

The range/vertical array is the odd criterion and the value to search is the even.

Comment: Thumbs up for making it work with both Arrays and Ranges, yet there must be (have been?) something easier and smaller, I guess.

Comment: @Vityata the worksheet will allow the multiplication/addition of arrays, but vba does not.  That is the root of the issue.  As to why....I do not know but I assume since we can loop in vba but not in formulas(at least till they invented the dynamic array formula) they created the ability in the worksheet but not vba.